# Treating null elements as empty string in Dart-XML library

Tags: xml, dart

There is a situation where the returned response from the web service is as below:

```
email xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

Parsing this tag in null safe with:

```
if (item.getElement('email') != null)
      email = item.getElement('email')!.text;
```

returns an empty string, where it should return a null,
Is this an issue in [Dart-xml](https://pub.dev/packages/xml) library?

Answer (score 2):

Well, for your null safety, please do not use `!`, it just shows you have not found the right flow yet. It's a crutch. Sometimes neccessary, but you can do better:

```
final emailElement = item.getElement('email');
if (emailElement != null) {
      email = emailElement.text;
}
```

I don't think XML makes a difference between null and an empty text. There is no text, that is the point and your parser seems to get that just fine. If you *need* this to be null, you can just set it to null if the text is empty:

```
email = emailElement.text?.length == 0 ? null : emailElement.text;
```

Or you could use `dart_extensions` and instead of checking for null explicitely, use their `isNullOrEmpty` extension method, which also return true if the string is non-null, but empty. Then you don't have to bother with the difference.

---

The library you are using [explicitely says](https://pub.dev/packages/xml):

> Limitations
> [ ] Doesn't validate namespace declarations.
> [ ] Doesn't validate schema declarations.
> [ ] Doesn't parse and enforce the DTD.

So I'm not surprised it does not recognize the namespace or it's definitions.

I guess you could write an extension method on an xml element yourself that returns the text, or if this attribute is set, returns null.

Comment: There might be some situations where we need to differentiate between null and empty string related to certain business cases. So each can mean different approach of handing.

Comment: Why do you think it *should* return null. If this should return null, how would a node look that returns an empty string in your opinion?

Comment: It's mentioned in the xml file that it's null (nil=true)
email xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>

Were i to send an empty String, i would do:
<email></email>